# selecting column ranges via sym and enquo with dplyr::select

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

### BLUP: Is it possible to use `sym`/`enquo` to pass column *ranges* to `dplyr::select`?

Consider the following tibble with columns A through E:

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(4)
d = as_tibble(setNames(as.list(rnorm(5)), LETTERS[1:5]))
d
## # A tibble: 1 x 5
##       A      B     C     D     E
##   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 0.217 -0.542 0.891 0.596  1.64
```

I can select a range of columns using the column operator `:`, e.g.

```r
select(d, B:D)
## # A tibble: 1 x 3
##        B     C     D
##    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 -0.542 0.891 0.596
```

I can even pass this range as a quosure:

```
cols = quo(B:D)
select(d, !!cols)
# same result as above
```

But I can't pass it as a symbol:

```r
colsym = sym("B:D")
select(d, !!enquo(colsym))
## Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'A:C' not found
```

This is problematic when column range selections are being used e.g. inside an R package.

In my real-world example, I'm selecting multiple ranges of 20-40 columns, so I'd like to stick with using the `:` operator rather than writing out multiple 20-40 element vectors and using `enquos` (which I assume would work, but I haven't tested it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to pass the non-syntactic name `B:D` as a symbol -- what you want is an expression. You can use `rlang::parse_expr` to convert a string to an expression:

```
cols <- rlang::parse_expr("B:D")

select(d, !!cols)
## A tibble: 1 x 3
#       B     C     D
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 -0.542 0.891 0.596
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. This works perfectly for both single column (`parse_expr("B")`) and ranges (`parse_expr("B:D")`)